# WindowSoftInputMode and ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

My Android app's main activity looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="60dp"
        android:paddingTop="53dp" >

        <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/billAmountText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/billAmount_string"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/billAmount"
                android:layout_width="173dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/billAmountText"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In order to make sure the background image (defined in the first RelativeLayout) does not get squeezed when the keyboard pops up, I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan` in the manifest file for my activity. All good with the background and layout now, nothing gets resized.

But the problem is that my ScrollView doesn't work now because I suppose the system thinks the window doesn't need resizing due to my above modification to the manifest - so the ScrollView is not activated. The opposite happens when I take `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan` out, the scrolling works, but the background gets squeezed when the keyboard pops out.

Is there any way to code it so that my background doesn't get squeezed, and my ScrollView still works? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use in your activity the property `windowSoftInputMode` with the following values:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"`

I don't know if it's necessary but you can try to add to your layout's `ScrollView` tag the `fillViewPort` to `true`.
So it should look like something I show you below:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

        <!-- Other Views -->
</ScrollView>
```

Let me know about your progress.

Comment: Thanks but no luck. Essentially, I want adjustResize to apply to the Scrollview, but I want adjustPan to apply to the RelativeLayout which hosts the background.

Comment: I ran into this problem. Wish you guys had found a solution :/

Answer (score 1):

In your scrollview put a relative layout, child 0 is an imageview, and child 1 is your content. Use the imageview for your background image (src) rather than the background of the scrollview. The imageview will respect scaleTypes, whereas the background of a layout will not.